# Finding area of triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a triangle, the average of any two sides is $6 cm$ more than half of the third side , then find the area of the triangle **(in$\ cm ^ {2}$)**

Comment: Since these are separate questions, you should post them separately. Also, you should include you own thoughts on the question. For example, what have you tried? What process or which formula do you think you need to use?

Comment: Actually .. I am new here so i didn't know that we had to post questions differently .. So from now on I'll post questions separately. And as for what I've tried , If anyone posts any hint or solution .. I just tell them what I had been doing wrong the whole time

Comment: Actually, the two questions are close relatives, solving either one will quickly lead to a solution of the other. Maybe use algebra (let the sides be $a,b,c$), and/or use symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a *hint*, I'll give a big one:

If $a,b,c$ are the side lengths, then Heron's formula says $$A=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}2\cdot\color{red}{\frac{a+b-c}2}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{-a+b+c}2}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{a-b+c}2}}$$

The red factors are precisely the average of two sides minus half the third one.

Now... What's the sum of the three red factors?